# SQL Order - Two different tables with one same key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
Table A:  ID Items Data Pos
Table B:  ID Apples Oranges Pos
```

And what I need to get all results from Table A and B ordered by position.
How can I do this? SELECT * FROM Table a and b orderby pos?

So for example the result should look like this:

1. Result from Table A with Id 1 Items 10 Data 5 and Pos 1
2. Result from Table B with Id 1 Apples 3 Oranges 3 and Pos 2
3. Result from Table B with Id 2 Items 4 Data 4 and Pos 3
4. Result from Table A with Id 2 Apples 7 Oranges 8 and Pos 4

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question with the actual database.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `union all` with an `order by`:

```
select ID, Items, Data, Pos
from tableA a
union all
select ID, Apples, Oranges, Pos
from tableB b
order by Pos
```

This is standard SQL so it will work in all the databases you mention.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I have an additional column in tableA? Then my union is showing me an error.

Comment: @PlicPl . . . In this query, the columns are chosen explicitly, so there additional columns in one table or the other don't pose a problem.  So, don't use `*`.

Comment: and what could I do if I need to use * ? Maybe "Join" would be a solution?

Comment: @PlicPl . . . You never *need* to use `*`.  List the columns so they are identical.  In a `union` on two different tables, it is bad practice to use `*`.